# How to specify python version in a conda virtual env

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.x

I am running a working project in my new position.

I believe virtual environment was created in it as I see:

```
$head bm3.py
#!/usr/bin/env /opt/bm3_venv/bin/python3
```

bm3_venv is the name of env created with requirements.txt (using virtualenv?)
$ ls -la /usr/bin/env
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 28992 Jun 30  2016 /usr/bin/env

The bm3.py is presumably using python3 for the entire project, not only from the above first line in bm3.py but also seen in some other python scripts using print('asdf') which is a python3 grammar.

However I do see in the project there are python2 grammar print 'asdf', i.e.

`/data/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.12.0-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.29/bin/../lib/impala-shell/impala_shell.py` is used when executing bm3.py and impala-shell.py is written in python2 grammar.

That means, in the current working project, when running bm3.py, it is using python3 but in the same running python2 is also somehow used.

How could this happen?

BTW, where can I download the original copy of impala-shell.py for the parcel of CDH-5.12.0-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.29?

Thank you very much.

UPDATE:

In the existing environment the first line of bm3.py is:

```
/usr/bin/env /opt/al2_venv/bin/python3
```

This specifies using python3 in this bm3.py

In the impala-shell.py used in the existing environment the first line is:

```
/usr/bin/env /usr/bin/env python
```

This specifies using python2 in this impala-shell.py

Now, the question becomes how does `/usr/bin/env` work here?

If I ran it in the existing environment, I get a list of variables settings like below:

```
> XDG_SESSION_ID=224064 SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED= TERM=xterm
> SHELL=/bin/bash HISTSIZE=1000 SSH_CLIENT=192.168.103.81 50182 22
> PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/home/xxxx/perl5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/tableau/tabcmd/bin:/home/rxie/.local/bin:/home/rxie/bin
> PWD=/home/xxxx JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest LANG=en_US.UTF-8
> KDEDIRS=/usr SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED= HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
> KRB5CCNAME=FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1377008653_sw88z6 SHLVL=1 HOME=/home/xxxx
> PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=:/home/xxxx/perl5 LOGNAME=xxxx
> QTLIB=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/lib SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.103.81 50182
> 192.168.101.231 22 LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1377008653
> QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib64/kde4/plugins:/usr/lib/kde4/plugins
> PERL_MM_OPT=INSTALL_BASE=/home/rxie/perl5
> _=/usr/bin/env
```

What is this env for and how do I use it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have the answer now:

I believe this is by design that python allows any python script (despite its python grammar) can specify the interpreter's version in the script's first line starts with **#!** like
`#!/usr/bin/env /opt/bm3_venv/bin/python3` in bm3.py, meaning the entire script is written in python 3; at the meantime, when impala-shell.py is used during the job running, the first line in impala-shell.py specifies the python interpreter - which is **python 2.6.6** - comes with the built-in python in Cloudera's CDH.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running `python 2` which you can verify using `python -V` in the Bash, now how could it be using `python3 print()` is by using `from __future__ import print_function` in the first line of your code, which from python 2.6+ ports/makes avialble the print function of python3 to python2.

Comment: Thank you for your input here. However, I think it is the reverse case, `#!/usr/bin/env /opt/bm3_venv/bin/python3` specifies clearly it is using python3, the impala-shell.py is using python2.

Comment: @mdivk after seeing the edits in the question the only response I have is opinion based and not certain, I will try to investigate a bit more, to reach a conclusion, in meanwhile if you want the opinionated answer, let me know.